# Add element inside a 2-D array's arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I had a question I just couldn't find the answer to. Say I have something like the following:

```
var test = [{"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3", "d": "4"}];
```

Now, say I wanted this test array to have an *additional* value based on some predetermined condition. I could do this:

```
if(cond) {
    var test = [{..., "cond": true}];
}
else {
    var test = [{...}];
}
```

In essence, I want the array key to exist if the condition holds.

I tried the following so far:

```
test[0]["cond"] = true; // (similar to how php does it, I thought)
test[0].push("cond":true");
```

But they did not quite work as I intended (or at all). How would I achieve the above? It would avoid a lot of code duplication.

Comment: Is it one extra variable you need in the array, or with each value of the array and extra variable?

Comment: Your first approach is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/5v5nky9v/

Comment: this is not a 2d array though, it is an array with 1 object inside at the moment, saying that you can still access the objects elemts using test[0]["cond"]

Comment: _"did not quite work as I intended"_? What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test[0]["cond"] = true;
```

Should actually work as well as

```
test[0].cond = true;
```

Take into consideration that it is not actually a 2D Array, it's an Array of javascript Objects that have different methods than arrays. For instance, javascript Object does not have a `push()` method.

Answer (score 1):

A `Object` is not an `Array`. You have a `Object` so you can't use `push`.

You can use the first method:

```
 var test = [{"a": "1", "b": "2", "c": "3", "d": "4"}];

 // Here you condition
 if (cond === true) { test[0]["cond"] = true; }
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4oab70f9/)